# проблемы с установкой модулей в anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Возникли проблемы при работе в `Jupyter notebook`. Все модули установил в анаконде. Но при запуске любой программы импортирую модуль, но каждый раз выпадает ошибка `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NAME'`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример Установка модулей в кобре

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ты менял версию Python ? Если да , то попробуй запустить на другой версии

Comment: вы уверены что запустили Jupyter Notebook из дистрибутива Anaconda а не из другой инсталляции Python?

Comment: Премного благодарю) именно в этом была проблема)